# Re-create session scoped JSF managed bean programmatically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, session-scope, recreate

I'm using Mojarra 2.1.29 and have a session scoped JSF managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserContext{

   //staff

}
```

and a spring bean:

```
public class UserReproducer{
    private User user;

    public void reporoduce(){
        if(user == null){
            //Here I need to recreate the userContext managed bean
            //do some other staff
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, I need some kind of custom scope in JSF, i.e. to re-create the `userContext` bean from scratch when the condition is satisfied. Is it possible to do in some way? By recreating, I mean cleaning all its properties down as it was created for the first time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Invalidate the session, to destroy a session scoped bean:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

Another option to log out from Spring Security is to clear the context:

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

Comment: Is that session tied with spring security's session? I mean is that the same thing?

Comment: The SecurityContext object is saved within the http session yes.

Comment: Is it possible to invalidate the JSF-session somehow when the user's trying to log in?

Comment: Why not give the class a `reset()` method?

Comment: This solution invalidates the whole HTTP session. So it doesn't just clear the bean, but it invalidates the data from all the session and view managed beans linked to that HTTP session. It's not the most proper solution for the concrete question, what the OP asks can be done with @Kukeltje's workaround.

Comment: The accepted answer is like shooting a mosquito with an elefant

Comment: The lifetime of a sessionscoped bean ends, if the session ends. So you think its better to break the JSF scoping?